# how to access the array created from this pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, calloc

So I've created a pointer to make a new array with the calloc() function. I want to access the array from this pointer as an array, but I'm not sure how to do that. Basically I want the array my_array to be the same as the contents in the array starting at the *stack pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main (int argc, char*argv[])
    {
        int capacity=5, *stack;
        int my_array[3];
        stack=(int*)calloc(capacity, sizeof(int));
        capacity++;
        
        stack=(void*)(realloc)(stack, capacity*sizeof(int));
        
        my_array[0]=*stack;
        my_array[1]=5;
        
            
    }
```

Comment: As you wrote it, `my_array` is complete independent from `stack`. You can copy a value from stack as you do but there is no fixed link between the two. By the way, it is not very clear **what** you want to do and **why** you want to do it.

Comment: @Aquila For example you can use the subscript operator like my_array[0]=stack[0];

Comment: Do you want to copy contents of my_array to stack, or do you want my_array and stack to be the same array?

Comment: I wanted them to be the same array

Comment: Yeah he is saying it: I want the array my_array to be the same as the contents in the array

Comment: Why do you need two different names withing one short function to refer to the same content?

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted them to be the same array

Then you must have my_array an `int*` and make it equal to `stack`, and keep it synchronized each time you realloc stack.

At first glance, what you want to do will lead to unreliable software easily.